# how to store and access trained neural networks

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I just started learning NN recently on python with keras, I've a pretty obvious question that nobody seems to ever mention its answer.

the question is very simple.

**what happen after you get the data, build the model and train your network ?**

every tutorial go through this thoroughly, but never mention how to use your trained model or store it after that.

so for example I written this simple code with keras to train a network on MNIST :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, kernel_size=3,data_format="channels_first", 
activation='relu', input_shape=(1,28,28)))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3 ,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
#compiling
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
#fitting and training
model.fit(X_train, Y_train,batch_size=32, epochs=1, verbose=1)
```

now how do i store the final network and reuse it again after i close the the the editor ?

for example if i wanna build a simple web interface to upload a MNIST pic and run it through the pre-trained model and detect the answer.

How can i store the trained Model with Python , access it with JS or php, run the uploaded picture through it , and return the output back to the user.

thanks, and sorry if my question seems stupid or obvious.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example how you can save your neural network in keras in json and h5:

```
# serialize model to JSON
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("model.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
```

and this is how you can load it again:

```
# load json and create model
json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
# load weights into new model
loaded_model.load_weights("model.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")
```

Finally you can evaluate the loaded model on new test data:

```
# evaluate loaded model on test data
loaded_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
score = loaded_model.evaluate(X, Y, verbose=0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (loaded_model.metrics_names[1], score[1]*100))
```